# Graph algorithm/approach for finding two nodes that disrupts the graph the most

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to develop a way of retrieving a measure of disruptiveness when removing two nodes from a graph. So far I'm performing a collection of algorithms like multiple measures of centralities, degrees, pagerank etc.
Its obvious that it can be done by actually removing two nodes and then analyzing the resulting graph (or collection of graphs), but this is also time-consuming when there is O(N^2) combinations of two nodes.
Any help to steer me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: there are O(N^2) combinations of two nodes, not O(N!).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the KPP-Neg problem (Key Players Problem).

It is defined in terms of the extent to which the network depends on its key players to maintain its cohesiveness. It is a “negative” problem because it measures the amount of reduction in the cohesiveness of the network that would occur if the nodes were not present.

(As opposed to the KPP-Pos problem where you are looking for a set of network nodes that are optimally positioned to quickly diffuse information, attitudes, behaviors or goods).

Both KPP problems were defined in *[The key player problem](http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/events/summer_institute/2006/reading_list/borgatti/Borgatti_Key_Player.pdf)* [Borgatti, 2003] and *[Identifying sets of key players in a network](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1245034/)* [Borgatti, 2006]. See also "Key players" - a discussion by Yves Zenou [here](http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.224274.1423955213!/menu/standard/file/Zenou_Handbook_Oxford_REV2.pdf).

Many more approaches were suggested since these papers were presented. Just google *Key Players Social Networks*.